# Error al intentar llamar a mi api de node con mi frontend con angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, api, express, rxjs

espero estén muy bien, verán estoy tratando de conectar una api que he hecho node, tengo una funcional ya alojada en un servidor, pero para el front que estoy haciendo, he hecho un backend local para pruebas muy simple pero recibe los mismo parametros que mi backend ya en producción .

que es este.

```
const express = require ('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());
 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
});

app.post('/send-message',(req, res)=> {
    
    if (!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.message ) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            message : 'name, email and message are required'
        });        
    }

    const recived_message = req.body;

    console.log('peticion recibida');

    res.json({
        ok:true,
        message:'message recived',
        body : recived_message
    })
  });

 
app.listen(3000 , ()=>{
    console.log('runing on http://localhost:3000');
})
```

ahora estoy tratando de consumir esta api en angular, pero obtengo el siguiente error siempre que hago el post que la api, no importa si es la local de ejemplo o la que ya tengo en producción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que no explico es realmente es porque si en postman funciona correctamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

prácticamente solo estoy mandando el body al enpoind localhost:3000

y bueno respecto a mi código con angular , tengo lo siguiente:

El servicio de mensajes

```
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Msj } from '../main/models/messages';


    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class MessagesService {
    
        constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Messages Services Is running');
        console.log('URI', environment.MESSAGE_URI);
      }
    
      sendMessage(message: Msj) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        console.log('mensaje pasado', message);
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/send-message', JSON.stringify(message), {headers});
      }
    }
```

que es consumido por este componente:

```
import { Msj } from './../models/messages';
import { MessagesService } from './../../services/messages.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacto',
  templateUrl: './contacto.component.html'
})
export class ContactoComponent implements OnInit {

  clear = false;
  ready = false;
  wrong = false;
  testing = false;
  server = false;

  msj: Msj;

  constructor(private message: MessagesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.msj = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: ''
    };
  }

  working() {
    this.clear = true;
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {

    if (!this.clear) {
      alert('error por el catcha');
      return;
    }

    if (form.valid) {
      this.message.sendMessage(this.msj).subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          this.wrong = false;
          this.testing = false;
          this.ready = true;
          alert('Mensaje enviado');
          this.clean();
          console.log('respuesta:', response);
        }
        else if (!response.ok && 'response.message' in response) {
          this.testing = true;
          alert('error por intento de hacking');
          console.log('respuesta:', response);
        }
        else {
          alert('error desconocido');
          this.server = true;
          console.log('respuesta:', response);
        }
      }, (err) => {
        console.log('Hubo un error', err);
        this.server = true;
        });
    }
    else {
      this.wrong = true;
    }
  }


  clean() {
    this.clear = false;
    this.ready = false;
    this.wrong = false;
    this.testing = false;
    this.server = false;
    this.msj.name = '';
    this.msj.email = '';
    this.msj.message = '';
    this.msj.phone = this.msj.phone ? '' : null;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.ready = false;
    }, 5000);
    return;
  }

}
```

esta parte tiene su propio modulo, en el que hago los imports y exports, y bueno este es el modulo y mi  mi estructura de carpeta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno no se donde esta el error, la petición ni siquiera llega al servidor creo, porque utilizando una bandera que hace un console.log cuando llega una peticion post.

Comment: prueba agregar cors a tu servidor.

Comment: como hago eso?, tienes alguna guía amigo.

Comment: Instala esto https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors en tu servidor de node (npm i cors), cors en un middleware para que tu servidor lo utilice ponlo debajo del app.use(express.json()); asi: app.use(cors()) , no te olvides de requerirlo const cors = require('cors') básicamente cors lo que te permite es comunicar tu servidor con el cliente, si quiere saber mas en google hay mucha info, saludos.

Comment: gracias amigo lo probare

Comment: @Franco eso era, gracias hermano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir del 2018 la configuración de CORS y cabeceras es obligatorio tanto en el back como en el front (por la vulnerabilidad [Spectre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(vulnerabilidad))), para hacerlo funcionar localmente puedes intentar con un proxy desde angular, debes crear un archivo en el root de proyecto: `proxy.conf.json`

el contenido del mismo:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Para correr la aplicación con el proxy `ng serve -o --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Para ambientes de producción, QA y desarrollo basta configurar la cabecera Allow origin de la petición al dns tanto en la petición como en la respuesta

Te dejo una [liga](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers) que me sirvió bastante cuando tuve el mismo problema que tu.